# Looking for advice regarding a larger scale soxhlet extraction

Tags: organic-chemistry, equipment, extraction, alkaloids

I have successfully completed a few soxhlet extractions at a much smaller scale using a soxhlet extractor with ~200ml capacity.  With that, I was able to extract from ~100g of pre-powdered, sonicated leaf with good results.

I'd like to extract a total of 1Kg, so I need to scale up. However, this is something I haven't done before. I'm currently looking into soxhlet extractors with a much higher capacity.  I found a Soxhlet extractor on eBay with a capacity of 1000ml with 34/45 lower and 71/60 upper joints.  I have also found a 16" 4-bulb Allihn condenser (71/60).

I plan first to defat the leaf with hexane, then extract with methanol since the alkaloids I'm after (Mitragynine) are highly polar.

Questions:

- This condenser seems to have adequate cooling capacity, but I'd feel a lot better if someone could confirm or suggest a better option if there is one.
- I'm also curious about what the optimal size flat bottom flask/amount of solvent would be.  After looking at similar apparatus, I'm guessing a 2000ml flat bottom flask with 1000ml of solvent.
- Going from a 200ml to 1000ml capacity extractor, am I right to assume I can extract 5x as much powdered leaf?  In this case, ~500g?
- This apparatus will be quite heavy, and the center of gravity not ideal.  How best to support it safely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Condenser capacity depends on the heat applied and the temperature of the coolant. You don't want to be above about one-third of the condenser. What is the volume before the Soxhlet siphons? Maybe aim for about three times that at least. Always use clamps with a stand too.

Comment: @Beerhunter thanks for your comment.  I'm pretty sure I found the perfect condenser for the job.  I calculated the volume of liquid that could be held in that space and it came out to roughly 1000ml, that's without adding the leaf to be extracted.  I also ordered a 3000ml RBF with two necks and a thermometer adapter for the second neck.  It would seem I estimated correctly.  I also got a heavy duty lab support stand, tripod style with 36" length, 1/2" diameter, and some heavy duty clamps that could accept the larger diameter of the upper apparatus.  I hope that's enough!